# How to trigger the AssociationChanged event in EntityCollection?

Tags: c#, entitycollection

I have to triggered the AssociationChanged event in EntityCollection, but i don't know the underlying collection type, i tried with object like below but the exception throws

```
(source as System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<object>).AssociationChanged += CollectionView_AssociationChanged;
```

I don't know how to type cast `EntityCollection<>`

Could you please suggest on this?